# Getting length of connected joints

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Rope : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject hook;
    public GameObject linkEnd;
    public GameObject linkPrefab;
    public int links;

    public float range;
    public float maxRange;

    public float dist;

    void Start ()
    {
        GenerateRope();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        GetRange();
    }

    private void GenerateRope()
    {
        Rigidbody2D previousRB = hook.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        for (int i = 0; i < links; i++)
        {
            GameObject link = Instantiate(linkPrefab, transform);
            HingeJoint2D Hinge = link.GetComponent<HingeJoint2D>();
            DistanceJoint2D Distance = link.GetComponent<DistanceJoint2D>();
            Hinge.connectedBody = previousRB;
            Distance.connectedBody = previousRB;
            Hinge.autoConfigureConnectedAnchor = false;
            Hinge.connectedAnchor = new Vector2(0f, -0.1f);

            if (i < links -1)
            {
                previousRB = link.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            }
            else
            {
                linkEnd.GetComponent<LinkEnd>().ConnectLinkEnd(link.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>());
            }
        }
    }

    private float GetRange()
    {
        return range = Mathf.Round(Vector2.Distance(hook.transform.position, linkEnd.transform.position));
    }
}
```

is a gameobject instantiates series of chain links to form a various lengths of chains using hinge joint and distance joint.

I'm trying to get the length of this chain when it's instantiated, but having a hard time so. Moreover, the links are placeholders as of now, so their size may differ in future, so mathematically getting the length at initiation is quite necessary.

My guess was to find each distance joint's anchor position and connected anchor position and make use of them to calculate this, but I'm stuck...

Any suggestion or guide will help!
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DistanceJoint2D has a Distance property. You can sum the Distance of every joint to get the full length.

```
float ropeLength = 0f;
for (int i = 0; i < links; i++)
{
   ...
   DistanceJoint2D distanceJoint = link.GetComponent<DistanceJoint2D>();
   ropeLength += distanceJoint.Distance;
   ...
}
```

You might want to write a RecalculateLength() method that does this which you can call any time you change a joint distance so your length is always up to date, if you need it.

Comment: Thanks for kind elaboration! @Wayland Yutani
However, I actually did that before and what I got was quite different number output. Simply put: If there are 10 links have distance of 1f each what I get as CalculateLength() is 43f where as my 'range' from GetRange() that gets Vector2.Dsitance from start to end gives 33f.

Comment: The 'range' value from GetRange() is more likely closer value what I want. However, since it's real-time calculation and it is different from start of instantiation to finish of hanging I couldn't get things quite right by myself.